# Find word in list python

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say I have a list of unknown words:

l = ['bike', 'blue car', 'wheel', 'car']

I would like to write a script to determine which word appears twice in the list.
What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum([1 if 'car' in word else 0 for word in l])
```

As noted, this overcounts for words that have the letters 'car' in them like "care", "scar", etc...

In which case, it's better to just split along spaces.

```
sum([1 if 'car' in word.split() else 0 for word in l])
```

More generic word count dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

count = defaultdict(int)

for words in l:
    for word in words.split():
        count[word] += 1
        
print(count)
```

Comment: and in the case where I do not know the word which appears twice in the list ?

Comment: what if `l = ['car', 'cartography']` ?

Comment: @Romain suggest you clarify that requirement in your question. *"the word 'car', for instance"* could imply that the function should accept the word 'car' as a parameter.

Comment: I get a list of unknown string and I have to work out which words appear several times. I hope to be more clear

Comment: I have updated the answer to be more robust about word matching and also for generic word counting.

Comment: @Michael Cao, I edited my question to be more clear

Comment: What if the L is something like - ```L = ['blue car', 'red car', 'car', 'wheel', 'bike', 'bikes']```?

Comment: @DanielHao As in you don't want bike and bikes to be counted as separate, correct? At that point, you'll have to introduce an NLP library to do tokenization instead of a naive space split.

Answer (score 0):

The following works even if a word is inside of another, e.g. 'ell' and 'hello'

```py
import re

words = [...]
output = []
for word in words:
    comparisons = [re.findall(word, string) for string in words]
    comparisons = list((filter(None, comparisons)))
    if (len(comparisons) > 1):
        output.append(word)
```

It's not efficient, but someone with more python knowledge than me can try to make this neater and more efficient

Answer (score 0):

```
n = len(list)
r = 0
times = 0
entire_word = 0
word = 'car'
total_times = 0
while r < n or r == n:
    if word in list[r] and not word == list[r]:
      times = times + 1
      total_times = total_times + 1
    if word == list[r]:
      entire_word = entire_word + 1
      total_times = total_times + 1
    r = r + 1
    print('The word "' + word + '" was in the words in list for ' + str(times) + ' times.')
    print('The word "' + word + '" was the entire element in list for ' + str(entire_word) + ' times.')
    print('The word "' + word + '" was in the list for ' + str(total_times) + ' times.')
```

If you do not understand something say to me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```py
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(['a', 'b', 'a'])
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1})
```

If you need to count words instead of list items:

```py
>>> import collections
>>> import itertools
>>> l = ['bike', 'blue car', 'wheel', 'car']
>>> collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.split() for x in l))
Counter({'car': 2, 'bike': 1, 'blue': 1, 'wheel': 1})
```

Comment: Applied to the input `l`, that will give `{'bike': 1, 'blue car': 1, 'wheel': 1, 'car': 1}`